# How to locate Alien/Package/Deb.pm?

Tags: yum, non-root-user, alien

Try to install alien without root.

1. cd /tmp; mkdir alien; cd alien
2. yumdownloader --destdir ./ --resolve alien
3. for rpm in glob.glob("*.rpm"):
   rpm2cpio rpm | cpio -id
4. cd usr; export PATH=./bin:./sbin:${PATH}; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib:./lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
5. run ./alien, got below error:
   Can't locate Alien/Package/Deb.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at ./bin/alien line 295.
   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./bin/alien line 295.

I can find Deb.pm.
-> find ./ -name 'Deb.pm'
./usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Alien/Package/Deb.pm

Not sure how to make it locate Alien/Package/Deb.pm

Answer (score 0):

Found need to add path to @INC like below
export PERL5LIB=/tmp/alien/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl (Need to use full path.)